# Logstash on Windows: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: command-prompt, logstash

I just moved to a new computer and I cannot get logstash-1.4.2 to work. It work fine on my last computer. I am trying to run logstash with the following command.

```
logstsash agent -f myFile.conf
```

The content of myFile.conf is this simple file

```
input { stdin { } }
output { stdout { } }
```

Every time I run the command above I get the following error

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

I am running this command in command prompt from the bin folder within logstash. Both the logstash.bat and myFile.conf are in this directory.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do your new computer have install java?

Logstash is run on the jvm, so you need to install java first. If you have install java,
try to send the java path.

Please have a look at this [website](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2274), I think your problem it same with them.

Answer (score 0):

The logstash quick installation guides fail to mention that in Windows you need to create a new environment variable called `LS_HOME` which should be set to the root of your logstash installation (eg: `C:\logstash-1.4.2`).

If you still get this error then check that your `JAVA_HOME` is correct.

For help setting the environment variables, please see the following: [setting PATH variables](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml), replacing "PATH" with your relevant environment variable.